# Javascript timed redirect

Tags: javascript, function, redirect, google-chrome-extension, timer

I have setup a redirect based or wether or not a user is active on a page or not. Thanks to [this tutorial](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/detecting_if_the_user_is_idle_or_inactive.htm) I have 99% of it working. There's just one feature I'm stuck at.

The JS is part of a google chrome extension.

A redirect warning pops up after 2 seconds of inactivity on a page, and if there's no additional activity within 5 seconds - the page is redirected to google.com (using google.com for testing purposes only).

Once redirected to google.com the timer starts again after 2 seconds - I don't want this.

I only want the timer to start when the user is **active** on google.com (i.e touches the screen).

Do I need to add an additional stopTimer function somewhere?

I basically want the timer to be on every page apart from the home page (in this case google.com).

My code so far - I've created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/ekc0q88j/1/);

The google redirect doesn't work in JS fiddle, but does work in my live environment.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.display = "none";
div.style.height = "18em";
div.style.width = "30em";
div.style.marginTop = "-9em";
div.style.marginLeft = "-15em";
div.style.background = "#f2dede";
div.style.color = "black";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.padding = "20px";
div.style.top = "50%";
div.style.left = "50%";
div.style.border = "5px solid #ebccd1";
div.style.borderRadius = "20px";
div.style.textAlign = "center";
div.style.zIndex = "9999";
document.body.appendChild(div);

var timeoutID;
var timerID;
var idleTimeout = 5; 
var idleSecondsTimer = null;
var idleSecondsCounter = 0;

function setup() {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);

    startTimer();
}
setup();

function startTimer() {
    // wait 2 seconds before calling goInactive
    timeoutID = setTimeout(goInactive, 2000);
}

function resetTimer(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    clearTimeout(timerID);    
    goActive();
}

function stopTimer(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}

function goInactive() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;

    div.style.display = "block";
    div.innerHTML = "<strong>Inactivity detected.</strong> <p>Redirecting in <span id='countdown'>" + (idleTimeout - idleSecondsCounter) + " </span> seconds. <p>Please touch screen to cancel.";
    // show a count down here then redirect to google.com

    timerID = setInterval(function(){ 
        idleSecondsCounter++; 

        if(idleSecondsCounter >= 6) {
            clearTimeout(timerID);      
            window.location.href = "http://google.com";
        } 
        else {            
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = (idleTimeout - idleSecondsCounter);
        }
    }, 1000);    
}

function goActive() {
    div.style.display = "none";
    startTimer();
}
```

The times I'm using above are for testing purposes, will be increased in live environment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that content scripts are reloaded on a new URL when the page is redirected?

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm - so how does this effect my code or the answer provided below?

Comment: Combine this info with the answer and you'll see that `setup()` is executed unconditionally after the redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timer starts unconditionally on page load when `setup()` executes.

If you only want it to start after some activity, just remove the `startTimer()` from your `setup()` code - on any activity you'll call `resetTimer` that will start the process.

Comment: Thanks @Xan this seems to be working! This is for a touch screen kiosk, so one more possible issue. For example if a user opens a new window and walks away - that window will always stay open as the user hasn't interacted with it, hence the timer won't start. Maybe I'm being pedantic! I basically want the timer on every page apart from my home page (in this case google.com). Thanks again for the main fix!

Comment: You can always test `window.location` just before redirecting instead of this fix if you want to _never_ redirect Google, or just apply this fix only if it _is_ Google.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean but thanks for the answer.

Comment: I mean a hypothetical check `if (!is_Google) startTimer()` inside `setup()` which can be achieved with `window.location`.